# Cannot inherit System.Window.Forms.Form class after manually change class name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, refactoring, compiler-errors

I have written a simple Form1 (inherit from Form) class in Visual Studio C#. All was good.

Then I wanted to change the name of the class and the namespace to something meaningful instead of the default 'WindowApplicationForm1' . I also changed the file name of the Form1.cs class to match the new class name (IRISReaderGUI and Com.Harmonysoft). First I manually rename the code, then compiled, the compiler gave me lot of error that I could not figure out. So I tried to rename my class and namespace using 'refactoring' menu. My code still didn't compile.

I did some research and change the 'IRISReaderGUI.Designer.cs' class name and namespace to match the new names. C# still didn't give me no joy.

1. **The compiler erros message was** :
   'Com.Harmonysoft.IRISReaderGUI.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method
   found to override'
2. **On the designer view it said** : The base class'System.object' can not be designed.

So I guess my IRISReaderGUI did not correctly inherit the System.Windows.Forms.Form class, this was confirmed by putting the mouse over the  Form word in the code, Visual Net does not popup the text describing the class, and pressing F12 does not get me to the Form definition.

Here is the code :

"IRISReaderGUI.Designer.cs"

```
namespace Com.Harmonysoft
{

    partial class IRISReaderGUI
    {
.......

}
```

---

"IRISReaderGUI.cs"

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Data.Odbc;
    using System.Data.OleDb;
    using System.Data.OracleClient;
    using Com.StellmanGreene.CSVReader;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;




      namespace Com.Harmonysoft
        {
            public partial class IRISReaderGUI : Form
            {
        ......
        }
```

---

I am new to C# and Visual Studio, I have previously worked with Java compiler and Vim editor mostly. Could anyone please help me to compile my code ?

Comment: So your question is essentially how to rename a Form?

Comment: Try to revert all change which you have made (2 steps as you mention), then use refactoring menu to rename what you want.

Comment: Better still, create a new form with the name you want, then copy and paste from the old one to the new. Then delete the old one.

Comment: BTW, please don't prefix your titles with "C#". That's what tags are for.

Comment: @JohnSaunders : Note taken about the prefix. Copy and paste to another file WORKS . Thank a lot , but could you tell me whyyyyy ?

Comment: revert your changes, then rename the file directly in solution explorer by right clicking on the file -> rename, when prompted to rename class select yes

Comment: Because there are a number of things that assume that the names will match. You simply missed one or more of those things when you tried to rename. Maybe you'd eventually find them all, but why not just start over?

Answer (score 3):

Forms in VS2005 and up are *partial classes*.  You edited the one part but not the other.  In the Solution Explorer window, expand the node next to the form and double-click the Designer.cs file to open it.

Using the Refactor + Rename context menu command is the better approach, it doesn't forget to edit the other source files as well.  It didn't work when you tried it because the damage was already done, the parts no longer had the same name.